# How to load other file(s) before Angular2 components

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Is it possible to load a certain file before Angular 2 loads? At the moment I'm loading `jQuery, bootstrap, file.js` globally in `angular-cli.json` including it like this will bundle up when you start Angular.

Is it possible to load `file.js` first before Angular? I will also need to load jQuery for this `file.js` as it has some jQuery `http` requests. I tried moving `../node_modules/jQuery` from `angular-cli.json` to my index.html.

Angular-cli.json - when file.js was in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "./assets/js/file.js"
  ],
```

index.html - when I moved jQuery and file.js in index I get jQuery not defined.

```
// in head tag
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/config/env.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just bundle in file.js as an external file? In the angular CLI, you do this by putting file.js in the "scripts" array of the angular-cli.json file. Look here: http://www.tcoz.com/newtcoz/#/errata and go to "Using External Scripts in Angular 2 (CLI)".

Comment: Yeah at the moment I am bundling it in angular-cl.jsoni, however I need to load file.js first before my component.

Comment: @MrNew Import the library before you starting the script, otherwise it wouldn't register itself.

Comment: @RomanC see the below conversation otherwise, can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

On top of .ts file where you want to use `jQuery`($), Import following :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Now you can use `$` for jquery related things.

Comment: Can I use that as global instead of putting it in a certain .ts?

Comment: installing globally using `typings` may be but Not sure. Let me know if you find anything such.

Comment: I need to load jquery before my file.js in my index.html for `$ajax` to work. So I'm not sure whether importing `$` in a .ts will work. Perhaps I need to load the file like normal.

Comment: I tried, adding it in typings.ts `declare $: JQueryStatic` that didn't work.